# Subscribe to secondary calendar using microsoft graph

Tags: c#, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to receive notifications when someone creates an event in his secondary calendar.
The user is the only owner so I thought the "me/events" resource should include the calendar.
But I only get notified when I create an event in the main Calendar.

I subscribed with the following configuration:

```
var requestBody = new Subscription
{
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl = "https://my.domain.de/custom/notification.aspx",
    Resource = "me/events",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2023-08-16T14:30:00.0000000Z"),
    ClientState = "secretClientValue",
    LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2",
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.